# alert view is not visible when adding a view as a subview of the application top window

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a situation where I'm adding my store view as a subview of the top window.
this is done by the following code:

```
NSArray* windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
int count = [windows count];
UIWindow* topWindow = [windows objectAtIndex:count - 1];
[topWindow addSubview:_storeView];
```

When I'm purchasing a product, in some cases (not sure exactly when and why) the in app purchase alerts, where the user needs to enter his app id credentials and approve the transaction are covered by my view and are not visible to the user.
Only when i dismiss my view i can see them and completing the purchase flow.

How can i make sure that those alerts will appear on top of all other views. and why is it not consistently, on some cases it is visible to the user and on some cases it isn't…

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are adding your view directly to the window ? i advise you to read the Apple documentation UIViewController programming guide.

The problem can be this lines of code :

```
NSArray* windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
int count = [windows count];
UIWindow* topWindow = [windows objectAtIndex:count - 1];
[topWindow addSubview:_storeView];
```

What is the root controller of your application ? are you using a container controller ( `UINavigationController`, `UITabBarController`,...). can you please show your AppDelegate code ?

Answer (score 0):

found a solution.

instead of using current window I'm creating a new window which is floating above other UI elements (like the system keyboard). 
I'm setting its window level property to UIWindowLevelStatusBar for displaying above status bar but underneath uialertviews